# How to add condition and change the color of table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript which will read the value from the JSON and creates a table dynamically in the HTML page.

```
<div style="width:700px;padding:20px;S">
            <h1 style="text-align:center"><i style="color:#ccc">ALM Server Availability</i></h1>

            <table id="records_table" class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Server Name</th>
                    <th>Availability %</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

JQUERY :

```
function availshow(series) {
    // 1. remove all existing rows
    $("tr:has(td)").remove();

    $.each(series.data.hostgroup.hosts, function (index, test) {
       $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').text(test.name),
            $('<td>').text(parseInt((test.time_up/86400)*100)),
        ).appendTo('#records_table');           
    });
 }
```

Now i need to check the condition if value of  `(test.time_up/86400)*100) < 100` , then i need to make that particular row into red color. How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, looping through each `tr` then looking for 2nd `td` value

```
$('#records_table tr').each(function() {
  var $td = $(this).find('td:eq(1)');
  var value = $td.text();
  if (parseInt(value) < 100) {
    $td.css('background-color', 'red');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JQuery fucntion should be something like this:

```
    var i=0
    function availshow(series) {
            // 1. remove all existing rows
            $("tr:has(td)").remove();

            $.each(series.data.hostgroup.hosts, function (index, test) {
            i=(test.time_up/86400)*100);
               $("<tr"+(i < 100 ? "class:'redBlock'": "")+">").append(
                    $('<td>').text(test.name),
                    $('<td>').text(parseInt((test.time_up/86400)*100)),
                ).appendTo('#records_table');           
            });
         }
```

And then create that said class in .css file with all the style you want:

```
.redBlock{
background-color:red;
}
```

Hope I could help.
Happy Coding :)

Comment: i really like this 1 better than palash answer. because you no need doing loop 2 times